# Measure Database performance on localhost

Tags: php, sql, caching, localhost

i have enabled query cache and set cache size, settings shown in the picture below.

[image: Cache Settings]

how do i measure the performance of the database and if the speed of my PHP web application improved after enabling cache, if i'm running on localhost?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You may get a better response if you were to ask this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/